# minifyEnabled true causes release app crash

Tags: android

I am having a security and tamper-proof problem with my application. If I just assemble it works fine.
[manifest file image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AXTS.png)
Then when building the android release when minifyEnabled is true in build.gradle, the app crashes. At the same time, I can no longer identify what the problem may be.

Comment: Hi there - please attach the crash logs and the manifest (feel free to remove the package name)

Comment: I have seen this many times. ProGuard rules are missing for some dependency.

Answer (score 1):

with minifyEnabled, proguard remove classes that apparently are unused. Maybe you have classes that are only used by firebase then these classes will be deleted and your app will crash. So all you need to do is add the "keep" annotation to these classes.

```
@Keep
public class ClassDeleted
```

Comment: This is the best answer and it helped me a lot. You are the best.

Comment: This solution worked for me also, the problem was in creating a ViewModel via factory - `ViewModelProvider(this, viewModelFactory)[MyViewModel::class.java]` Just needed to add @Keep to MyViewModel class declaration